# Django: how to handle data that doesn't fit in a model

Tags: python, django

I have been working with Django for a while now and I think I'm getting the hang of it. Working with database data is pretty easy with models. However, I am really struggling to find a way to handle data for which making a model isn't really an option. For example, I want to have a "welcoming" text on my homepage that should be editable from the admin interface. Other examples are an email address for contact information, a path to a file (eg resume) stored on the server, links to social media, ...

Making a model for this kind of data seems unnecessary to me, as there will only be one entry in the table for that model. Up until now I have been using [Constance](https://github.com/comoga/django-constance) for a while, which is pretty nice. However, I'm interested to find out how I should handle this kind of data with "vanilla" Django

Comment: [Settings module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/)

Comment: The settings module looks like a good place to put this, but this means I have to commit/upload/redeploy my site each time I edit e.g. the welcoming text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a model for bits of text to be displayed on your site. It could simply have a unique name, and a text field.

```
from django.db import models:

class SiteText(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    text = models.TextField
```

Then it's easy to create a simple bit of text in the admin panel, or in code:

```
SiteText.objects.create(name="greeting", text="Welcome to my site!")
```

And accessing that from within your site is as simple as:

```
SiteText.objects.get(name="greeting")
```

It's fine if this model has only one instance, but it also allows you to store other snippets of text in the database and easily access them from other parts of your codebase.

For your other examples, paths to resumes, email addresses, links, these all sound like they could be fields on a user model, or separate tables with foreign keys to a user. Storing things like this in the database is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: This sounds quite reasonable, but does it mean that the "Django way of doing things" always relies on creating models for any kind of editable data?

Comment: A model is just an interface to the database. The database is where you're going to store data that is expected to change in the normal course of the operation of your site. So, yeah, you'll usually be creating models for any data that can change.

Comment: Obviously, there are other ways to persist and edit data. Templates, for example, use the filesystem. However, the nice things about models are (1) all the django tools to operate on them, like the admin site and (2) databases are _really good_ at persisting and editing data.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. But where should I put such a model? It doesn't specifically belong to any of the existing apps that I already have. Hence a new app probably?

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably want a new app. When I started using django I was always very hesitant to start new apps, but having worked with it for a while, I've realized that creating a new app for even small pieces of functionality isn't a bad thing.